# AppGyver for mobile apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, appgyver

I want to learn how to build a mobile App using [AppGyver](http://www.appgyver.io/)...I started looking in the official documentation but I have found 'Composer', 'Steroids', 'Supersonic'...I intend to use Javascript and AngularJS but I can't fully understand the difference between the Composer and the other platform components...any one who has already used this technology can help me with a short explanation between those components and what should I use between them please...Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Supersonic is the UI framework (similiar to Ionic) that allows you to build hybrid mobile apps for iOS/Android. http://www.appgyver.io/supersonic
- Composer allows you visually build mobile and web apps with the possibilty of extending components with custom html/javascript. https://www.appgyver.com/
- Steroids is the toolchain you use when developing Supersonic applications.
  http://www.appgyver.io/steroids

I.e. your choice is between Supersonic and Composer. Based on that you "want to learn how to build a mobile app" I'd say you should have a look at Supersonic. There is a good tutorial available at http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/tutorial/first-mile/